# Java для чего нужна строчка?

Tags: java, сокет

Здравствуйте. [Разбираю этот код](http://javatalks.ru/topics/7772). Никак не могу понять, как работает вот эта строчка

```
new Socket("localhost", port); // создаем фейк-коннект (чтобы выйти из .accept())
```

Объясните, пожалуйста.

UPD: Тем более сейчас проверил, без неё тоже работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть в том, что accept блокируется в ожидании нового подключения. По приходу подключения, accept возвращает сокет. Сам accept заворачивается в цикл (в коде это `void run()`), который принимает подключение, обрабатывает это и идет на следующее подключение.

Но если пользователь сервера захочет его остановить, то ему нужно как то разблокировать accept. Для этого и создается фейковое подключение, а перед этим выставляют флаг завершения работы. цикл, где крутиться accept, проверяют этот флаг и завершают цикл по необходимости.

В целом, это нормальная "реализация для бедных". Представьте себе ситуацию, когда пользователей у сервера много и они постоянно подключаются. И может произойти ситуация, когда флаг выставлен, и в этот момент заходит пользователь. Его уже не обслужат и закроют. А попытка подключиться фейковым в этот момент приведет к ошибке. Также возможна ситуация, когда подключиться не получиться (а ошибки код глушит - что уже печально - даже в лог не пишет) и сервер может не завершиться (если пользователей нет).

Нормальный метод заключается в том, что нужно для серверного сокета вызвать метод close. В этом случае accept выдаст исключение, которое можно корректно обработать.

Comment: Кажется я начал понимать... То есть в этой строчке сервер как бы подключается сам к себе? чтобы accept вернул это соединение?

Comment: да. и не "как бы", а в самом деле.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, всё понял.